# refactor this basic code that determines if number is in tens, hundreds, thousands etc

Tags: javascript, refactoring

```
 if (n<100) {
     x = 10;
 } else if (n<1000) {
     x = 100;
 } else if (n<10000) {
     x = 1000;
 } else if (n....
```

etc. etc.

Is there a nice concise, scalable method for this type of problem? My brain has decided to stop working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var x = Math.pow( 10, Math.floor( Math.log(n) / Math.log(10) ) );
```

This one might be preferable, because it's available as a constant so it doesn't need to be calculated each time:

```
var x = Math.pow( 10, Math.floor( Math.log(n) / Math.LN10 ) );
```

It basically comes down to rounding down logarithmically.

---

**Edit:** Because a combination of `log` and `/` often tends to result in errors, it might be a good idea to round the quotient as well (currently, `Math.log(1000) / Math.LN10 === 2.9999999999999996`).

```
var x = Math.pow( 10, Math.floor( Math.round( Math.log(1000) / Math.LN10 * 1e10 ) / 1e10 ) );
```

This rounding might result in new errors, but for 'normal' inputs the answer is now more often correct.

Comment: `Math.log10` is your friend in this case.

Comment: @tadman: Yes, there is no `Math.log10` in JavaScript. Could be you confuse it the [equally named .NET method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.log10.aspx)?

Comment: There's a `Math.LN10`, but no `log10`, you're right. Every other library has it, including Ruby.

Comment: @tadman: Sometimes JavaScript is indeed just missing some helpful operators/methods.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Is there a name (mathematical or otherwise) of "rounding down logarithmically"?

Comment: @Peter Kelly: I cannot find a concrete definition, but this subject is close: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using recursion:

```
function find_place( x, n ) {
    return x >= 10 ? find_place( x/10, ++n || 1  ) : Math.pow( 10, n || 0 );
}

find_place( 3 );    // 1
find_place( 33 );   // 10
find_place( 333 );  // 100
```

---

**EDIT:** *Fixed to use `x >= 10` instead of `x > 10`.*

---

Here's a version that removes the need for `Math.pow()`.

```
function find_place(x, n) {
    return x >= 10 ? find_place(x / 10, (n || 1) * 10) : n || 1;
}
```

---

Or run effectively the same code in a loop instead of a recursive function to speed it up a bit.

```
var x = 12345,
    n = 1;   // n will hold the result
while (x >= 10) {
  x /= 10;
  n *= 10;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it returns `100` for `x = 1000`.

Comment: @pimvdb: Ah, yes it does. Should have used `>= 10`. Fixing... Thanks. :o)

Comment: Your recursion functions are interesting. Just for the record I was checking which one would be faster, and your second one is a big improvement. http://jsperf.com/find-place

Comment: @pimvdb: Thanks for the test. I thought it may be a little faster, but didn't think it would be that much, though in Chrome 13, the numbers are a little closer.

Comment: ...though yours is definitely fastest in Chrome 13. http://jsperf.com/find-place/2

Comment: That's surprising - mine is 100x faster on Chrome 12, whereas on Chrome 13 it isn't (looking at the Browserscope).

Comment: @pimvdb: That's odd. I wonder what happened in v13. FF5 shows a significant performance increase with yours as well.

Comment: The last one was what I had in my head (somewhere in the back...) from 1st year college all those years ago. The recursive solutions are interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
x=Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.LN10));
```

Answer (score 1):

One cleanup is to make this its own method, with return values.  That way you avoid all the `else if`'s

```
...
if (n < 100) return 10;
if (n < 1000) return 100;
if (n < 10000) return 1000; 
...
```

This isn't as good, as general, as clean as using the pow() function @pimvdb suggested, but it is a good more general way to clean up code with an "else-iffy" feel like the one presented.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar and came up with the following:

```
x = Math.pow( 10, ( '' + n ).length - 1 );
```

And some test cases, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TbkR3/):

```
n = 33;   // x = 10
n = 213;  // x = 100
n = 1776; // x = 1000
```

Don't know if the performance is any better than all the `log` stuff, and this assumes `n` is an integer.